# SAS Looping Through Macro Variables

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

I want a program to which loops through a list of macro variable names, and returns the value of each macro variable within a %DO loop, instead of returning just the macro variable name.

```
%let macro_list = AA BB CC;
%let loop = %sysfunc(countw(&macro_list.));

%let AA = 123;
%let BB = 456;
%let CC = 789;

%macro test();

    %do i = 1 %to &loop.;

%let var = %scan(&macro_list.,&i);
%put &var.; /* I want this to return 123 not AA!!!*/

    %end;
%mend test;

%test;
```

Currently the macro returns the values of AA, BB, CC instead of 123, 456, 789.

I would also be open to other ways of implementing this. Thanks!

Comment: When you ask for `&var`, it returns the value of `var` which is the one from the list. Ask it for `&&var.` and it returns `&AA`, which then resolves to 123. Google "resolving double ampersand SAS" for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add more `&`

```
%put &var = &&&var ;
```

or use `%superq()` function.

```
%put &var = %superq(&var) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried two && during my troubleshooting, should've gone to three &&&!!! %superq() looks neat and should be easier to read.